# Control email login

Tags: php

I have a small problem on this form, I would like the check to be done also on the user's email and not only on the password.
Because now his behavior is in the case of an email registered in the db but an incorrect password leaves an error message, but in case of an incorrect email no check is issued.

I would also like to include an email check

```
<?php ob_start(); session_start(); ?>
<?php
$messaggio = "";
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
    include 'connection/cnt.php';
    $email = $connessione->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $password = $connessione->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    $query = $connessione->query("SELECT *FROM collaboratori WHERE email='$email'");

    if ($query->num_rows > 0) 
    {
        $data = $query->fetch_array();
        if (password_verify($password, $data['password'])) {
        $_SESSION['collaboratore'] = $data['ID_Collaboratore'];
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        window.location = "home.php";
        </script>   
        <?php   
    }
    else
        $messaggio = "Please check your inputs!";

    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The indentation in your post is misleading. The `else` looks like it goes with `if ($query->num_rows > 0)`, but it actually goes with `if (password_verify($password, $data['password'])`.

You need an `else` block for the `$query_num_rows` check.

You also shouldn't escape the password, since you're not using it in a SQL query (unless you also made the mistake of escaping it before you called `password_hash()` when saving the password).

```
<?php ob_start(); session_start(); ?>
<?php
$messaggio = "";
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
    include 'connection/cnt.php';
    $email = $connessione->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $query = $connessione->query("SELECT *FROM collaboratori WHERE email='$email'");

    if ($query->num_rows > 0) 
    {
        $data = $query->fetch_array();
        if (password_verify($password, $data['password'])) {
            $_SESSION['collaboratore'] = $data['ID_Collaboratore'];
            ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            window.location = "home.php";
            </script>   
            <?php   
        } else {
            $messaggio = "Please check your inputs!";
        }
    } else {
        $messaggio = "Please check your inputs!";
    }
}
?>
```

You can also simplify it by combining the assignment and check. There's no need to test `num_rows` -- if there's no matching rows `$query->fetch_array()` will return `FALSE`.

```
<?php ob_start(); session_start(); ?>
<?php
$messaggio = "";
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
    include 'connection/cnt.php';
    $email = $connessione->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $query = $connessione->query("SELECT *FROM collaboratori WHERE email='$email'");

    if ($data = $query->fetch_array() && password_verify($password, $data['password'])) {
        $_SESSION['collaboratore'] = $data['ID_Collaboratore'];
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        window.location = "home.php";
        </script>   
        <?php   
    } else {
        $messaggio = "Please check your inputs!";
    }
}
?>
```